# Syntax error : Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am making a Chrome Extension and i have some problems

I want to make a fetch() to Anilist.co and to avoid problems, i want to use await but i have a syntax error :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqurb.png

Here is the code :

```
async function getAnimeProgress(animeId) {
    var result;
    chrome.storage.local.get('access_token', function (items) {
        var query = `
        query ($id: Int, $page: Int) {
          Page (page: $page) {
            media (id: $id) {
              id
              mediaListEntry {
                  status
                  progress
              }
            }
          }
        }
        `;
        var variables = {
            id: animeId,
            page: 1
        };
        var url = 'https://graphql.anilist.co',
            options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + items['access_token'],
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    query: query,
                    variables: variables
                })
            };
        function handleResponse(response) {
            console.log('handleResponse exec !');
            result = response;
        };
        function handleError(e) {
            console.error(e);
        };
        await fetch(url, options).then(handleResponse).catch(handleError);
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: The error is at `await fetch(url, options).then(handleResponse).catch(handleError);` and as said to Manuel, the await brokes the function but i need that the cal finishes to return result and not 'undefined' :/

Answer (score 1):

Are you supposed to have a single quote in these lines:
  var query = 
; 
It seems your then making the query VAR a String.

Comment: the await fucks everything up, when i am testing into a simple snippet, it's working.

Comment: Did you remove the single quotes from this code block?
 var query = ` <---HERE
        query ($id: Int, $page: Int) {
          Page (page: $page) {
            media (id: $id) {
              id
              mediaListEntry {
                  status
                  progress
              }
            }
          }
        }
        ` <--- HERE;

Comment: I think it appears it is the await() but when I copy and paste your code I have a compile error in your VAR QUERY code block.